# Stripe keycloack parse server best practice for monthly subscription

Tags: javascript, server, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm implementing stripe to a website which use parse server for the backend and keycloack for the security. Everything is running on the same server using docker.

Here's the flow to manage subscription.
1 When a user ask for checkout the backend generate a new stripe checkout session and redirect to the user.
In the back I save the user ID and the checkout session ID.
2 The user does checkout and is redirected to the success url.

3 when The back recieve a checkout.session.completed, we look for the user based on checkout session and save the subscription ID
Update keycloack user role to say it's a subscribed user

4 When the back  get from stripe an  invoice.payment_failed event or when the subscribition isn't renewed I need to remove the role on keycloack server.

I already have done the major part in an express js app but I was wondering what solution would be the best for security, reliability and maintenance :

1. Create a paiement service in nestjs which handle the stripe events and use his own mongodb database to save paiement data( user session and subscription) and update user roles on keycloack
2. Create a paiement service in nestjs which handle the stripe events and save user checkout session and subscription using parse server object rest api    and update user roles  on keycloack
3. Do everything in parse server cloud code but Is that safe to store keycloack account into parse server cloudcode ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd go with the third option. Saving the keycloack account on server side (cloud code) should be safe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply How can I add some library in parse server like fetch ?

Comment: Parse Server is essentially an Express.js middleware so you are actually working on a node.js app. You can install any npm package you want, like node-fetch.

Comment: thanks for your help I did the third one and it's pretty clean.